# Take substring from a string dynamically in Oracle v11/v12

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, substr

I have these strings and in Oracle I should take substrings dynamically.

```
Input:
Record: 11, Entità : CustomerOrder, attributo: DESCRIPTION non conforme al formato atteso
Output:
Entità : CustomerOrder, attributo: DESCRIPTION non conforme al formato atteso

Input:
Record: 3, Entità : CustomerOrder, attributo: DESCRIPTION non conforme al formato atteso
Output:
Entità : CustomerOrder, attributo: DESCRIPTION non conforme al formato atteso
```

Could you kindly help me with the query?

Thanks so much

Comment: You should say what is the rule to identify the substring, without it we can only guess and provide 3+ different answers

Answer (score 1):

Just use `INSTR` to find the index of the first comma and then take the substring starting 2 characters later (to skip the comma and white space):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( input, INSTR( input, ',' ) + 2 ) AS output
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( input ) AS
SELECT 'Record: 11, Entità : CustomerOrder, attributo: DESCRIPTION non conforme al formato atteso' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Record: 3, Entità : CustomerOrder, attributo: DESCRIPTION non conforme al formato atteso' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | OUTPUT                                                                         |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Entità : CustomerOrder, attributo: DESCRIPTION non conforme al formato atteso |
> | Entità : CustomerOrder, attributo: DESCRIPTION non conforme al formato atteso |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32625606333f27b085de513babce1f6c)*

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you need to extract the substring starting with the pattern `Entità :`  upto the end of the line, use [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490) function such as

```
SELECT 'Entità : '||REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'(.*Entità : )(.*)','\2') AS output
  FROM t;

OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Entità : CustomerOrder, attributo: DESCRIPTION non conforme al formato atteso
Entità : CustomerOrder, attributo: DESCRIPTION non conforme al formato atteso
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aff61c6bb887e795757c234bc9352689)</kbd>